# Recover from LDAP error without restarting

Tags: java, ldap, rundeck

Sometimes, one cannot login with LDAP, showing this:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldapserver:636
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:252) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1616) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2847) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:348) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:262) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:226) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:280) ~[?:?]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:185) ~[?:?]
[...etc...]
```

in service.log

Usually, restarting rundeck fixes this. Is there a way to recover without restarting ?

Thanks

Cheers

Xavier

Comment: Login to what? Please be mindful that no one here can see your screen or knows about your application architecture :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the LDAPS service is unreachable (network error, etc...) for more time than the default Rundeck timeout value (default = 0).

Increase the value on the `timeoutConnect` parameter (in ms) on your `jaas-ldaps.conf` file (or create it).

Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#login-module-configuration) (Scroll down and check the `timeoutConect` section).

Comment: Unfortunately, this parameter is already set
Thx

Comment: I mean, try to increase the defined value in that parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a try on it
FWIW, the full stack trace is here : https://pastebin.com/GMVz1i8k